# Is there a way to exclude packages based on size rather than its name, while updating via dnf

Tags: fedora, dnf

I use a wifi that restricts downloads that are sized more than 45mb. Is there a way i can filter the results from '*dnf update*'? so i can update just the ones that are downloaded and ignore the rest. Without this the downloads stop half way.

I know about 'exclude'. But i guess it is based on the **name** of the package. Is there anything that excludes based on the **size** of the package? Finding out the packages that are above the size limit and then excluding them one by one seems to be cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such functionality currently. However, one could use the [DNF API](http://dnf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) to write a plugin which does this.

If you want to try hacking something up at the command line, you can get a list of pending updates sorted by size with:

```
dnf repoquery --upgrades --queryformat '%{size} %{name}'
```

or in general query the size of a package with, for example for firefox:

```
dnf repoquery --upgrades --queryformat '%{size}' firefox
```

You could do that, and then feed all packages below your limit into an update command. However, the complexity comes in when trying to install those updates, because you can't quickly tell if a small package also depends on updating a larger one. Any quick shell script hack to work around this would quickly reach — or exceed — the complexity of writing a plugin.

Comment: Ok ... how about a shell script ? ... would that work .. grep the output from the dnf update and do something with it ? ... possible ?

Comment: Updated with some ideas. You might also consider a) checking with the wifi provider about changing this limit for package updates or b) using VPN or some other tunneling solution to avoid the issue. The per-file limit seems a bit silly — why is downloading a million small files okay but one big file banned?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But that is how it is. I know its really silly. Its actually kind of funny. Its very easy to bypass this if you have a server somewhere. You can split the files and download them. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing a simple script. It was a silly solution to a silly problem you might say. I type in 'dnf update' and get all the packages that need to be installed. Copy paste it in a file (should be automated). Use that file in a script to download packages individually. Like 'dnf update package_name'. Since this goes for individual packages, my downloads don't get stalled in the middle and im able to update what ever is possible. Needs a lot of refinement, yes. But i did not bother about them since it gets my work done one way or the other. I will refine it to work perfectly without user intervention when i get time i guess. Not that its a big deal,
https://github.com/johananj/dnfupdate-tweak but in case you want to re-use